# When is useful use "silent" for tty?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, tty

If the `tty --help` command is executed it shows

```
tty --help
Usage: tty [OPTION]...
Print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.

  -s, --silent, --quiet   print nothing, only return an exit status
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Therefore when `tty -s` is executed it returns nothing

**Question**

- When is useful use *silent* for `tty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Script that is run regularly from cron,
# but also sometimes from the command line.

interactive=false
if tty -s; then
    echo 'Running with a TTY available, will output friendly messages'
    echo 'and may be interactive with the user.'
    interactive=true
fi

# etc.
```

In short, it provides a way of testing whether a TTY is attached to the current shell session's standard input stream, which indicates that the script may be able to interact with a user by reading from the standard input stream.  You can also do this using the test `[ -t 0 ]`, or the equivalent `test -t 0`, which is *true* if fd 0 (standard input) is a TTY.

The `-s` option and its variations are non-standard (not part of [the POSIX specification of `tty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html)), and [the OpenBSD manual for `tty`](https://man.openbsd.org/tty.1) also mentions the `-t` test (which *is* standard):

> `-s`
> Don't write the terminal name; only the exit status is affected
> when this option is specified.  The -s option is deprecated in
> favor of the “test -t 0” command.